# What is the correct word/pharsal verb for this?

Tags: word-usage, american-english, spoken-english

A new movie is released. People are going to watch it. So we'd better take out some time too , before it "goes down " or gets "replaced" by a new one? Is this correct?

Comment: *We should set some time aside to see it before it **goes away**.*

Comment: or 'While it's still in theaters'...